# Get next value (not null) in the same column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, isnull

I have a SQL query which return the lines with Ids and Name,

There are some rows which are NULL, so i used ISNULL('row', -1) so set those null rows to -1.

> ISNULL(AORL_AOR_Id,-1) as 'AORL_AOR_Id',

But for better development and those rows in the same column can exist with the same value, I would like to ask that is there a way to get the next not null value in the same column to set to the current null value ?

[image]

So in my case, those rows with -1 will get the value of 28735.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (ISNULL is product specific...)

Comment: @jarlh : i'm using SQL SERVER

Comment: Which release of SQL Server?

Comment: @dnoeth : SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Bad luck, in SS2012 there's FIRST_VALUE.

Comment: @dnoeth : yeh really, is there any same functionality like that in 2008 ?

Comment: Not really, you need some unique sort column, add a ROW_NUMBER in a CTE and then join using `t2.rn = t1.rn + 1`, but this will fail if there are two consecutive values.

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no "previous" or "next" row, unless you have a column specifying them.  There is a good possibility that you can fix the query that generates the data to generate what you actually want.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question, include the query and ask how you can turn the `NULL` values into what you really want.